# Duality in multi-objective optimization

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems

I hope that have a great time.

I have a vital problem. Actually,  I need to work with duality for multi objective optimization problems. However, many of references have analysis basis. My question is that does there exist any references which can help me to solve my problem?

Best.